# Archiva SMTP Real domain name required for sender address Error

Tags: archiva

I installed the stand alone Apache Archiva 1.3 Maven repository and I am having trouble configuring the SMTP settings for the e-mail validation. I configured the SMTP address by changing the mail.smtp.host property in jetty.xml. I was not able to find any documentation on Archiva's site for configuring this.

```
  <New id="validation_mail" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
    <Arg>mail/Session</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.mortbay.naming.factories.MailSessionReference">
        <Set name="user"></Set>
        <Set name="password"></Set>
        <Set name="properties">
          <New class="java.util.Properties">
            <Put name="mail.smtp.host">mail.xyz.com</Put>
          </New>
        </Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>
```

Here is the error that I am getting when I try to register a user

```
Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 5.5.4 <testuser@localhost>... Real domain name required for sender address
```

caused by

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException; nested exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 5.5.4 <testuser@localhost>... Real domain name required for sender address
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added the security.properties file to the conf directory as mentioned [here](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M4/adminguide/customising-security.html). I then added the properties listed below to the file. The email.from.address property is the answer. These properties can be found in the [Redback config-defaults.properties](http://archiva.apache.org/redback/configuration.html).

```
email.validation.required=true
email.from.name=Archiva Admin
email.from.address=archivaadmin@xyz.com
email.validation.subject=Archiva Maven Repository
```

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it using the 1.4 page. The 1.3 page is no longer available. I also added a link to Redback because that link doesn't work from the Archiva site.